# How to Improve Blobs Detection Accuracy?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Consider the following picture: it is a frame from a video of few people talking to each other. I have tried to do blob detection on that video, but when two persons are near each other, it is considered as one blob. 
Is there a way to improve the blob detection, so that I can detect people more efficiently?![Blobs][1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called `Occlusion`.

This is a typical problem where you need help of `Kalman Filter`.

Kalman filter takes previous values and predicts the future values. It is highly useful in noisy situations or inaccurate situations.

A lot of discussions are there in SO, which you can find by simple searching. But i found two of them really useful

1) [Question on tracking a moving ball using Kalman filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713379/question-on-tracking-a-moving-ball-using-kalman-filter)

2) [Use Kalman filter to track the position of an object, but need to know the position of that object as an input of Kalman filter. What is going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749084/use-kalman-filter-to-track-the-position-of-an-object-but-need-to-know-the-posit)

And [Kalman filter is already implemented in OpenCV](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=kalman#kalmanfilter) and inbuilt functions are available.

Also check this SO on multiple blob tracking : [Multiple Blob Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821514/multiple-blob-tracking)

This is not only method. You can find plenty of papers regarding this on googling.

**[Paper 1](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:r-h912e0B4gJ:cvrc.ece.utexas.edu/Publications/tracking_multiple_body_parts.pdf%20how%20to%20track%20multiple%20blobs&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESji6NjTEqlHfJr9B578AKSeh9hssxPUqFylmM5bAxPSRzItSsLzGPd2eXPGlXtGFK7LXrrFE74E4TyvCxYDuPODD1mdneJooJqpP6EfWt2dzkeuLFRtkymC0e8g417nWZCdFFYg&sig=AHIEtbR0AcUrz7cG2gZpdKTffXBCP6PpnQ)** : This paper explains another method. Might be useful.

A lots of papers exclusively on this subject can be [found here.](http://www.yale.edu/perception/Brian/refGuides/MOT.html)